# ECharts linechart not loaded

Tags: javascript, echarts

I'm using `ECharts` in order to create dynamically some line charts.
They are created within `div` which are dynamically created in my js script based on the server response. The problem is that they are not shown.

I did some test and I noticed that if a div has height 0, the chart will not be shown. So I moved the charts initialization when the `div` is visible: also now I can't see anything.

```
var chartsIds = []; // div id list
var lineCharts = []; // charts array
var optionLineCharts = [];
```

this is the charts initialization function

```
function init_echart(id,  index) {
    if ($("#" + id).length) {

        var echartLine = echarts.init(document.getElementById(id), theme);        
        echartLine.setOption(optionLineCharts[index], true);
        lineCharts.push(echartLine);

    }
}
```

which is called for each div id in this moment `if ($("#block").is(":visible"))`.

The options are like this one:

```
var echartLineOptions = {
            tooltip:
            {
                trigger: "item",
                formatter: function(params) {
                    var date = new Date(params.value[0]);
                    data = date.getFullYear() +
                        "-" +
                        (date.getMonth() + 1) +
                        "-" +
                        date.getDate() +
                        " " +
                        date.getHours() +
                        ":" +
                        date.getMinutes();
                    return data + "<br/>" + params.value[1];
                }
            },
            legend:
            {
                data: []
            },
            toolbox:
            {
                show: true,
                feature: {
                    mark: { show: true },
                    dataView: { show: true, readOnly: false },
                    restore: { show: true },
                    saveAsImage: { show: true }
                }
            },
            dataZoom: {
                show: true,
                start: 70
            },
            xAxis: [
                {
                    type: "time",
                    splitNumber: 2
                }
            ],
            yAxis: [
                {
                    type: "value"
                }
            ],
            series:
                []
        };
```

where the series are populated (correctly) based on the server response. I can see with the debug all the data and the series.

I noticed that even if the biggest div is visible, the div created by the charts initialization function has height = 0. I can't find any solutions..any help is really appreciated!!

Comment: Apparently, having just a visible `<div>` is not enough, the DOM must have a pre-defined width and height prior to `echarts` initialization. Bottom line is that the `init` method should be able to calculate the width and height of the DOM. You can use a custom CSS class to define the width and height of your chart divs and give it a try.

Comment: Excuse me for the late answer, yes. I had to specifiy a min-height of the div in order to be sure that it has a size != 0. Moreover, since that I had multiple tabs, I had to intercept the tab change event in order to "draw" the charts.

Comment: @Annjawn thanks!! Worked for me

Comment: @AnBisw how to define the custom CSS on the echarts instance?